# Unwanted request generated with LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq, linq-to-entities

In order to optimize a method, I look at each line of my code as well as each generated request in order to eliminate a maximum of them. I have serious doubts about the following part:

A planning contains several projects. A project contains several activities. I first load all activities for future needs. This generates, as expected, a "SELECT WHERE IN" request on the Activities table

```
var planningProjectIds = p.PlanningProjects.Select(x => x.PlanningProjectId).ToList();
var planningActivities = _db.PlanningActivities.Where(x => planningProjectIds.Contains(x.PlanningProjectId));
var planningActivitiesArr = planningActivities.ToLookup(x => x.PlanningProjectId);
```

Here is a first attempt. The following code generates an unwanted request (between log lines 9b and 10)

```
foreach (PlanningProject pp in p.PlanningProjects)
{
    // ...
    sw.WriteLine("9");
    pp.PlanningActivities = planningActivitiesArr[pp.PlanningProjectId].ToList();
    sw.WriteLine("9b");
    pp.PlanningActivities = pp.PlanningActivities.OrderBy(x => x.Position).ThenBy(x => x.PlanningActivityId).ToList();
    sw.WriteLine("10");
    // ...
}
```

Here is a second attempt. This code does not generate a query

```
foreach (PlanningProject pp in p.PlanningProjects)
{
    // ...
    sw.WriteLine("9");
    pp.PlanningActivities = planningActivitiesArr[pp.PlanningProjectId]
        .OrderBy(x => x.Position)
        .ThenBy(x => x.PlanningActivityId)
        .ToList();
    sw.WriteLine("10");
    // ...
}
```

Could you tell me the reason for that? Thank you in advance ;)

Here is an extract of the log where we can see the extra request

```
9b
Opened connection at 06/07/2017 10:22:15 +02:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[PlanningActivityId] AS [PlanningActivityId], 
    [Extent1].[FriendlyName] AS [FriendlyName], 
    [Extent1].[PlanningProjectId] AS [PlanningProjectId], 
    [Extent1].[ActivityId] AS [ActivityId], 
    [Extent1].[ScheduleID] AS [ScheduleID], 
    [Extent1].[Position] AS [Position]
    FROM [dbo].[PlanningActivities] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[PlanningProjectId] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '847' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 06/07/2017 10:22:15 +02:00

-- Completed in 7 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 06/07/2017 10:22:15 +02:00

10
```

Do not hesitate to tell me if I could forget valuable details to solve this small problem :)

Comment: which part is unwanted? do you mean performance issue, not runtime error?

Comment: I assumed that `pp.PlanningActivities` collection trying to retrieve data from DB, where `planningActivitiesArr[pp.PlanningProjectId]` is an array generated from previous query and you just created a list from stored array data in memory without querying the DB again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first block, `pp` is still connected to the db context so will [lazily load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_1) the `PlanningActivities`. You may get better performance and fewer queries if you do everything in a single query and use [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.include(v=vs.103).aspx) to load child entities. For example:

```
var projects = _db.Plannings
    .Where(pl => pl.PlanningId == 1234)
    .PlanningProjects
    .Include(pl => pl.PlanningProjects
        .Select(pp => pp.PlanningActivities))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Then I should do this for each project? If I understand correctly whenever I go to call pp.PlanningActivities it will want to touch the database, even if I modified the collection myself?
Is it a bad idea to detach the object from the database? I would like to modify my planning object and not have to create 36 additional lists and change my views ...

Comment: I made a slight change to start with the base `Planning` object (assuming some naming here.) Doing it like this will get all of the data you need and you can iterate around the hierarchy without touching the database again. In fact, it's a good idea to closed the database connection as soon as you are done with it, so wrap the query in a `using(var db = new Context()) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

When you enumerate `p.PlanningProjects` you are only getting the `PlanningProject` entity as local variable `pp`.

It does not populate any navigation properties at this point.

```
foreach (PlanningProject pp in p.PlanningProjects)
{
    // ...
}
```

Once you call the property getter to fill `PlanningActivities` for the `PlanningProject` between "9b" and "10" the database is queried for those planning activities:

```
sw.WriteLine("9b");
pp.PlanningActivities = pp.PlanningActivities.OrderBy(x => x.Position).ThenBy(x => x.PlanningActivityId).ToList();
sw.WriteLine("10");
```

Hence the query:

```
SELECT ....
FROM [dbo].[PlanningActivities] where [PlanningProjectId] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

With `@EntityKeyValue1` being the `PlanningProject.PlanningProjectId` of your `pp` variable.

If you don't want the extract queries, use include to load all of the data at once.